# What's the probability of one binary classifier better than another knowing the results over a sample of size $N$?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, machine-learning

Assuming that classifier_1, classifier_2 have an unknown hit ratio $α, β$, what is the probability that $α>β$ if after doing an experiment on a sample of size 20 classifier_1 gets a hit ratio of 80% and classifier_2's ratio is 60%? And what is the probability that $α$ is greater than $β$ by at least 10%?
If we have a model in production with a given test accuracy and we subsequently develop a new model that improves those test results, how likely is it worthwhile to change the model?

If I had an estimation of the probability distribution of $α$ and $β$, I could solve the question easily. I know that the probability distribution of $α$ and $β$ is $0$ in 0 and 1. Should I expect it to be centered in $α$ and $β$? How do I obtain those probability distributions?

Comment: 1. Please define "hit ratio" in a self-contained way in the question.  2. The question might not be answerable without knowing what prior you have.  The question of what prior to use is not a question about mathematics.  3. It has been previously suggested that you ask on Stats.SE.  I think that is more suitable than here.  Please don't cross-post on multiple sites; if you ask on the wrong site, you can delete the question on one and ask on the other -- after addressing all feedback that has been provided.